# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'instancemethod' and 'instancemethod'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a BMI Calculator using Python and Tkinter interface graphics

here is my code:

```
def createButtons(self):

    self.buttonCalculate = tk.Button(self)
    self.buttonCalculate["text"]="Calculate"
    self.buttonCalculate["fg"]="red"
    self.buttonCalculate["bg"]="yellow"
    self.buttonCalculate["font"]=("arial","16","italic","bold")
    self.buttonCalculate["height"]=3
    self.buttonCalculate["width"]=15
    self.buttonCalculate["command"]=self.actionPrint
    self.buttonCalculate.pack(side="top")

    self.buttonExit = Button(self,text="Exit",fg="red",bg="blue",command=root.destroy)
    self.buttonExit.pack(side="bottom")

def createLabels(self):
    self.label = tk.Label(self)
    self.label["font"]=("arial","16","italic","bold")
    self.label["height"]=3
    self.label["width"]=45
    self.label["text"]="Type your weight(kg) and your height(cm) respectively"
    self.label.pack(side="left")

def dataEntry1(self):
    self.edit = tk.Entry(self.master,width=35)
    self.edit.grid(row=2,column=0)

def dataEntry2(self):
    self.edit = tk.Entry(self.master,width=35)
    self.edit.grid(row=1,column=0)

def actionPrint(self):
    print("Test")

def dataCalculation(self):

    dataCalculation=(self.dataEntry1/(self.dataEntry2*self.dataEntry2))
    print("your BMI is: ", dataCalculation)

root = tk.Tk()
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'instancemethod' and
>   'instancemethod'

No Erro occurs but it doesn't work, I don't get the BMI value I'm trying to calculate

How to get the data?

Comment: Those are methods that create widgets. You need to get the value the user types from the resulting widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your title is happens because you try to do mathematical operations between methods.

What you want to do are operation with the values contained in the `Entry`.

You probably should have something like:

```
def createButtons(self):
    self.buttonCalculate = tk.Button(self)
    [...]
    self.buttonCalculate["command"] = self.dataCalculation
    [...]

# set the entries: these two method are likely called in a ``__init__`` or setup method
def set_data_entry1(self):
    self.edit1 = tk.Entry(self.master,width=35)
    self.edit1.grid(row=2,column=0)

def set_data_entry2(self):
    self.edit2 = tk.Entry(self.master,width=35)
    self.edit2.grid(row=1,column=0)

# callback for e.g. a button: get the values of the two entries, converted them to float and do the operations
def dataCalculation(self):
    dataCalculation=(self.get_data_entry1())/(self.get_data_entry2() * self.get_data_entry2())
    print("your BMI is: ", dataCalculation)

def get_data_entry1(self):
    return float(self.edit1.get())

def get_data_entry2(self):
    return float(self.edit2.get())
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried but it only prints the "Test" example

Comment: That's because the button is connected with the print action and not the data calculation. See my edit

Comment: If this solves your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: Done. Helped me a lot